Is there an analog method to `__args__` for finding the return type in Python?
I'm working with Python's typing system and I've found that I can use __args__ to get the argument types of a callable. For example:
from typing import Callable

callable_type = Callable[[int, str], float]

print(callable_type.__args__)  # Output: (<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>)

In this case, __args__ returns a tuple containing both the argument types and the return type. Is there a similar method or attribute that specifically gives me the return type of a callable? I'm looking for something like:
return_type = callable_type.__return_type__  # Hypothetical attribute
print(return_type)  # Desired output: <class 'float'>

Is there a built-in way to achieve this in Python's typing system, or do I need to implement my own solution? (i would rather use a built-in way. To keep my code simple)
